# Signal Integrity: rise time or signal frequency, which is more dangerous?

Tags: signal-integrity, high-speed

I was watching the below video from Rick Hartley. In this he says more than signal frequency signal rise time is more problematic. A signal with rise time in the range of picoseconds and frequency in the range of kHz is more trouble maker (SI, EMI/EMC issues) compared to a signal with nanoseconds of rise time and frequency in the range of some MHz or GHz.

May I know why and what makes signal rise time more problamatic compared to frequency?

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=52fxuRGifLU

Comment: 1) You should study Fourier analysis: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_analysis 2) realize that a step function (a signal that changes from 0 V to 1 V instantaneously) has an **infinite** frequency spectrum. 3) a pure sinewave of 1 kHz has a frequency spectrum of only one peak: at 1 kHz.

Comment: And don't say "dangerous" as a signal containing high frequencies isn't more or less dangerous than one that doesn't. Example: 10 kV, 50 Hz from mains distribution point: very dangerous yet only 50 Hz. 2.5 GHz Bluetooth transceiver: very low power so completely harmless despite using 2.5 GHz.

Comment: Humm ... Effects of "radio frequencies" are not really known (or accepted) on "human bodies" ... Anyway, do not stand in front of a "radio frequency antenna", too long ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If a signal is periodic, and it is not a simple sine wave, then it will be a sum of fundamental frequency plus harmonics. As the harmonic number increases, amplitude tends to decrease. How fast it decreases with frequency depends on how fast the risetime is, and how sharp the corners of the "square wave" are. [Link](https://www.edn.com/rule-of-thumb-1-bandwidth-of-a-signal-from-its-rise-time/).

What matters regarding signal integrity and EMI is not really the frequency of the signal itself, but the frequency of the high harmonics that have enough amplitude to contain enough energy to cause problems.

Basically, if you have a low frequency, fast rise time signal, it's like having a burst of RF happening on every edge. If the frequency rises, it happens more often, so total RF power in the signal is higher. But it does not become zero just because frequency is lower than some psychological threshold.

Slow signals with fast edges are a gotcha, because we think "it's slow" and route it like any other slow signal: just a trace, maybe not over continuous ground plane, through connectors, etc. This means the resulting PCB will have plenty of "involuntary" structures that can act like antennas, couplers, resonant circuits, etc, at RF.

If the signal has slow edges, these structures exist but they are not excited, so they do nothing, although they can still act as receiving antennas for incoming EMI if the dimensions happen to match the incoming frequency.

But if the signal has fast enough edges, so that it contains harmonics at a frequency that excites these structures, or a short enough wavelength that is no longer large relative to the dimentions of PCB structures then you have a problem. For example a through-hole component on your pcb becomes a dipole antenna, transmission line effects turn your edges into double edges and the receiving chip loses bits, a cut in the ground plane becomes a slot antenna, etc.

So yes, it depends on frequency. But it's not the frequency of the signal, it's the highest harmonic that has enough energy to cause problems, and that strongly depends on rise time. So in the end, rise time really matters.

Answer (score 2):

> *May I know why and what makes signal rise time more dangerous compared
> to frequency*

You have `signal integrity` as a tag and so I presume you mean "problematic" rather than "dangerous". You also mention "signal" in your words and that is usually taken to mean a voltage signal but, is equally applicable to a current signal.

So, the main explanation for fast changing voltages is in the capacitance formula: -

$$i = C\cdot \dfrac{dv}{dt}$$

Basically this tells you that if the voltage acorss a 1 uF capacitor is changing at 1 volt per second, then the current that passes through the capacitor is 1 μA. If the voltage were changing at 1 million volts per second (or 1 volt per μs) then the current through the capacitor is 1 amp.

So, if you have a signal wire carrying a nice clean analogue signal and it is positioned close to another wire that has a voltage change of 1 volt per μs, then there is current forced into the analogue signal wire. That current depends on the capacitance between the two wires and, if they are very close, that capacitance could be several hundred pico farads.

With 1000 pF (1 nF) of capacitance and 1 volt per μs on the disrupter wire, the current passed to the "victim" wire will be 1 mA. It doesn't sound very much but it could easily ruin your nice clean analogue signal.

Voltage rise and fall time are directly linked to passing disruptive currents between two wires.

The overall base frequency may be fairly low of course; the disrupting signal could rise at 1 volt per μs for 100 μs, then fall at the same rate for another 100 μs then be at 0 volts for 800 μs then restart. The base frequency is of course 1 kHz and, if instead, it was a small amplitude sinewave, it wouldn't be naturally regarded as a disrupting signal (unless it was very high in amplitude). Example: -

A sine wave of 1 kHz and 100 volts peak value has a maximum rise time of \$100 \times 2 \times \pi \times 1000\$. This equals 0.628 volts per μs. So, the sinewave described above is of the same order of dv/dt as the ramping 1 kHz waveform previously described.

Hence, both frequency and amplitude can be equated with rise or fall time.

There is similar story with inductive coupling formed from this equation: -

$$V = L\cdot \dfrac{di}{dt}$$

The disrupter is di/dt and, with two close wires, a di/dt change on one wire will magnetically induce a voltage in the other wire. This time we are interested in the amount of magnetic coupling between the two wires (because this defines how much di/dt on one wire produces an induced voltage on the other). But, di/dt is just as serious as dv/dt in many systems and circuits.